# How to inherit some candidates of polymorphic function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I want to define a function in a base class and a function with the same name and another signature in a subclass like this:

```
class A {
public:
  void foo () {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
  void foo(int x) {}
};

int main() {
  B b;
  b.foo();
}
```

But it causes compile error: `no matching function for call to ‘B::foo()’`.
If I comment `foo` definition in class B, it compiles.
How to solve the problem?

What I really want is to define a polymorhic interface in a base class and redefine semantic in child classes.

UPD: Thanks, the answers worked for this example. But it doesn't seem to work with templates:
sort.h

```
...
class Sort {
public:
  template <typename TArr>
  static TArr& sort(TArr& array) { return sort(array, array.size()); }
};

class BubbleSort : public Sort { // add inheritance
public:
  using Sort::sort;
  template <typename TArr>
  static TArr& sort(TArr& array, size_t len) {
     ...
  }
};
```

test.cpp

```
...
int main () {
  ...
  std::array<int, 5> test_array {3, 2, 5, 1, 4};
  BubbleSort::sort(test_array)
  ...
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
sort.h: In instantiation of ‘static TArr& Sort::sort(TArr&) [with TArr = std::array<int, 5ul>]’:
test.cpp:9:30:   required from here
sort.h:17:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘Sort::sort(std::array<int, 5ul>&, std::array<int, 5ul>::size_type)’
   static TArr& sort(TArr& array) { return sort(array, array.size()); }
                                               ^
sort.h:17:16: note: candidate: template<class TArr> static TArr& Sort::sort(TArr&)
   static TArr& sort(TArr& array) { return sort(array, array.size()); }
                ^
sort.h:17:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
sort.h:17:47: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
   static TArr& sort(TArr& array) { return sort(array, array.size()); }
```

Why does it happen?

UPD: Got that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `virtual`, the `A::foo()` doesn't define a polymorphic interface.

Anyway, you can make `A::foo()` visible via `B` with a `using` declaration:

```
class B : public A {
public:
  using A::foo;
  void foo(int x) {}
};
```

This provides polymorphism to the extent that you accept function overloading as polymorphism--i.e., `A::foo()` and `B::foo()` form an overload set, and the compiler chooses which to call based on the parameter(s) you pass (if any), the same way as if `B` contained two overloaded functions (with the same signatures as the existing `A::foo` and `B::foo`).

Answer (score 2):

> But it causes compile error: `no matching function for call to ‘B::foo()’`

Try [`using-declaration`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

```
class A {
public:
    void foo() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    using A::foo;
    void foo(int x) {}
};
```

> What I really want is to define a polymorphic interface in a base class and redefine semantic in child classes.

Well, you should make the base class function `virtual` an have the same parameters when override it. Otherwise, how the subclass function is supposed to be called via a reference/pointer to the base class?

Answer (score 1):

Function `f` from the derived class simply hides all the functions with the same name from the base class.

To solve it you can use a [using-declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

```
class B : public A {
public:
  using A::foo;
  void foo(int x) {}
};
```

Comment: I don't think that's a "problem". It's very much by design.

Comment: @KerrekSB Definitely, "problem" is not the best word in such context :)